# Setting Active Control on a form to a toolbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to set a toolbar to be the active control of the form, did something like this:

```
this.ActiveControl = this.Controls.Find("toolStrip2", false);
```

but it is saying it cann't contvert from Control[] to Cnotrol.

So how can I set that toolbar to be the active control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Find` returns array of Control instances whose name matches the string you pass to it. The first control in the array, if there is one, should be the one you are looking for.

You can do it using this code:

```
Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find("toolStrip2", false);
if (controls.Length > 0)
      this.ActiveControl = controls[0];
```